# How to avoid other jquery that is in other file

Tags: php, jquery

I have two jquery events on click of button.but i want to perform only one event.So how can i do that.
my code is as follow.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Demo #1</title>
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div align="center">
    <button id="mybtn">Some Button</button>
  </div>

<script>
  $("#mybtn").click(function(){
      $("#mybtn").fadeOut();
  });
</script>
<?php include('demo2.php'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is code for demo2.php

```
<script>  
  $("#mybtn").click(function(){
      alert("i am in included in demo2");
  });
</script>
```

now When i click on button Both Event is performed.so is there any way to perform one event that is store in current page not perform jquery that is included.

Comment: Why don't you just remove one of them?

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable to connect the selector to the event in page one do this

```
<script>
var selectFunction1=True;
$("#mybtn").click(function(){
  if(selectFunction1===True){
  $("#mybtn").fadeOut();
  }
else{return false;}

  });
</script>
```

And in demo2.php do this

```
<script>  
var selectFunction2=True;
$("#mybtn").click(function(){
if(selectFunction2===True){
  alert("i am in included in demo2");
}
else{return false;}
  });
</script>
```

Comment: and if i wants to apply on two button with same class and same query so what i have to do to avoid ?

Comment: the same think if the two button has the same event

Comment: Note that to avoid confusion when you have tags with the same class I think the better way is to use (this) keyword

Comment: sorry i doesent test and mark as answer but when i test it still works Both Query.